# How to model composite pattern in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, saxon

I am trying to work out how to model a specific style of serialisation in order to validate schema aware XSLTs against the schema (using Saxon).

A simple example of the xml would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootShape>
    <SQUARE width="10" x="1" y="25">
        <contains>
            <TRIANGLE rotation="180" x="1" y="34">
                <contains>
                    <TRIANGLE rotation="180" x="221" y="34">
                        <contains/>
                    </TRIANGLE>
                    <SQUARE width="10" x="1" y="25">
                        <contains/>
                    </SQUARE>
                </contains>                        
            </TRIANGLE>
        </contains>
    </SQUARE>
</rootShape>
```

the "style" of serialisation exports an object 'type' in capitals, and then the attributes/fields of the object in lower case. Leaf types (e.g. string, int, datetime etc) are modelled as attributes, whilst the references to other objects/values recursively follow the same pattern.

So...I can write a simple XSD against some of this quite easily.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="SQUARE">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="contains"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="TRIANGLE">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="contains"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="rotation" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="rootShape">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
                <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

(and this validates successfully) but I'm slightly stuck how to handle the "contains" relationship.

the cardinality of the relationship is 0 -> unbounded, but cardinalities are associated to a specific element, where I want to apply the cardinality to different choices/alternatives (i.e. rather like a union type).

any ideas?
I'm an xsd noob, I've looked at "types" and "alternative" but can't get anything sensible.

Answer (score 0):

achchc, you can apply cardinality constraints to choice....stupid me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="SQUARE">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="contains">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
                            <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
                        </xs:choice>                        
                    </xs:complexType>                    
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="TRIANGLE">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="contains">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
                            <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
                        </xs:choice>                        
                    </xs:complexType>                    
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="rotation" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="rootShape">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="SQUARE"/>
                <xs:element ref="TRIANGLE"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is a good use case for substitution groups.

Define an abstract element declaration named SHAPE, define SQUARE and TRIANGLE as members of the substitution group of SHAPE, and then use SHAPE in your content model wherever you want to allow either SQUARE or TRIANGLE to appear. Then when you introduce further shapes, you just need to add them to the substitution group.

Comment: so the issue here really is that this schema is going to be generated from (effectively) an ER diagram, automagically, so actually I'm not massively concerned about how concise it is, only its semantics....which I'm slightly stuggling with. There is a new question which defines a schema but using types, because of some horrid "type" alternative wrinkle in the serialiser.

Comment: the good news is, once I understand how to do a 0/n relationship of alternative/choices, then I can pretty much do everything I need.

Comment: I think I may take a look at substitution groups a bit later, it may be a sensible optimisation